# php function returning a string with a new line?

Tags: php

In my first 3 days in coding my homework. I successfully did it. But when I got to school, my code have a problem. I have an ajax form and some php functions.

Here is an example.

```
$i = 1
if($i == 1) {
   echo "yes";
}
else {
   echo "no";
}
```

The answer in my sample is **true**. But in my case it's always false. And I notice the ajax requests that the returned message was

```
    // new line
    // new line
yes
    // new line
```

That's why it's being false. What is the cause of this? I didn't put any **new line** in my code.

Answer (score 4):

You must have newlines somewhere :

- either at the beginning and end of your script
- or at the beginning and/or end of some file it includes

Note : make sure you don't have anything outside the `<?php ... ?>` tags : it would get sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

if your code doesn't include any html, simply open:

```
<?php
```

you don't need to close it. This will help you eliminate any whitespace or new lines

Answer (score 0):

If you want the easy way out of it, try this

```
ob_clean();
echo "yes";
exit;
```